# $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a compact subgroup

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Prove that $ \mathbb{Z}_p \subset \mathbb{Q}_p $ is a compact subgroup and show that this is the maximal compact subring.

Hint: use that every sequence of integers had a Cauchy sub-sequence with respect to the $p$-adic norm and that if $R \subset  \mathbb{Q}_p$ is a **compact** subring then $ \left| x \right| \leq 1 $ for all $x \in R$.

**Definitions:**
$\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the $p$-adic norm. Morover we let $\mathbb{Z}_p :=\{ x \in \mathbb{Q}_p : \left| x \right| \leq 1 \}$

**My idea:**:
We clearly have by definition that $ \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, since if $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ then we have $\left| x y \right|_p \leq 1 $ and $\left| x+y\right|_p \leq 1$ using the ultrametric property. In particular is a subgroup. Moreover by the hint we have that any subring is contained in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ hence is maximal. We are left to prove the compactness part.
We can see $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a metric space, with the metric induced by the $p$-adic norm, then I want to use the fact that in a metric space sequentially compact and compactness are equivalent notions. Then I want to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is complete (but don't know how), i.e. every Cauchy sequence converges, and I think that this is sufficient to prove that it is sequentially compact since every sequence of integers had a Cauchy subsequence which converge to some $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and I think that if it is true for integers then it is also true that any sequence of $p$-adic integers possesses a Cauchy subsequence as well. Anyway I found a little bit strange how it is stated the exercise.

Comment: The next thing, after correcting what that was supposed to be, is that you need to tell us what definition of $\mathbb Z_p$ you are working with. Seems like it is $\mathbb Z_p := \{x \in \mathbb Q_p: \lvert x \rvert \le 1 \}$, is that so? But then mazbe you should tel us what definition of $\mathbb Q_p$ you are working with. In particular, do we know that $\mathbb Q_p$ is complete?

Comment: You are right, i forget to say that $R$ is a compact subring not just a subring, and anyway i don't know how to prove the hint about $R$, do you know how to prove it? anyway... the definition of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the same, while as $\mathbb{Q}_p$ i have as definition: $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is defined to be the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with repsect to $\left| \cdot \right|_p$

Comment: Maybe it works that since $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a complete metric space (is a completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ so is complete) and since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a closed ball contained in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, in particular is closed, then we can deduce that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is complete as well?

Comment: What is the source of the exercise?

Comment: @Alma Arjuna the source is my professor

Comment: Regarding the hint: If $|x| >1$ then the sequence $x^n$ cannot have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: I think that I'm able to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is totally bounded, and thus since it is also complete (my previous comment should work), we have that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is compact. To prove that it is totally bounded, for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, say $x=\sum_{j\geq 0} x_jp^j$ and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then there exists an integer $y =\sum_{j \geq 0} y_j p^j \in \{1,\ldots,p^n-1\}$ such that the first $n-1$-digits are equals, i.e. $x_j=y_j$ thus $\left| x-y\right|_p = p^{-n}$ and thus for every $\epsilon >0$ we can cover $\mathbb{Z}_p$, with finitely many balls of radius $\epsilon$.